# QSettings on OS X 10.9 - unable to locate/clear it

Tags: macos, qt, settings, application-settings, qsettings

I have a Qt (4.8.5) based application running on OS X 10.9. The app uses QSettings class specifying app name and company. Plist file is created by QSetttings under:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.company_name.app_name.plist
```

The app works pretty fine in terms of saving/restoring preferences. Then I quit the app, delete *.plist file, run the app again and voila - it restored its preferences! **Based on what what file? Hot to delete it?**

I was unable to find the answer in the Qt doc for QSettings class.

Comment: Are you sure it restores its preferences or it actually resets to the **default** values?

Comment: The [source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/8f84a6e549b90286afb2e4af378ea8b271babcd5:) is where you *will* find the answer :)

Comment: Yes I'm sure it doesn't reset to defaults. The link to source code is great but I think it's also somehow related to app sandboxing in Mac.

Comment: This behaviour is still observed on MacOS 10.11.

Comment: See also [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303958) about the same problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In 10.9 (and higher) .plist files are being [cached](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20130908042828630).
So once you have deleted a .plist file, the cache must be refreshed. Either log out or execute the following command in Terminal:

```
killall -u yourusername cfprefsd
```

Comment: On 10.11, logging out doesn't seem to work, but the command does. Thanks!