# How to delete preferences for Mac application?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm developing a Mac desktop app using Cocoa and Objective C in XCode. I need to simulate a clean reinstall, but I can't figure out how to completely delete all preferences for the application.

I found the file at /Users/username/Library/Preferences/com.MyApp.plist and deleted it, but the preferences still persist when I reopen the application.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Open Terminal. `man defaults`. Read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting plist file does not reset app on Mac OS 10.9 Mavericks, 10.10 Yosemite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19303958/deleting-plist-file-does-not-reset-app-on-mac-os-10-9-mavericks-10-10-yosemite)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the console tool `defaults` (in a `Terminal.app` window) with the bundle identifier of your application, like this:

```
defaults delete "com.domain.AppName"
```